# Java SWING GUI leaves to console after running thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface, chat

So I have class which is called ChatClient and works with ChatServer class as a multichat encrypyion messenger. So I have some Swing components like below and I initialize them in my ChatClient constructor:
public static ChatClient client;

```
// GUI ELEMENTS
BufferedReader in;
PrintWriter out;
JFrame frame; 
public static JTextArea userText;
JTextArea DisplayMessage;
JLabel connectInfo;
JToggleButton tglbtnConnect;
JToggleButton tglbtnDisconnect;
JLayeredPane layeredPane;
JLayeredPane layeredPane_1;
JRadioButton rdbtnAes;
JRadioButton rdbtnDes;
JRadioButton rdbtnCbs;
JRadioButton rdbtnOfb;
JPanel panel;
JLabel lblServer;
JLabel lblText;
JLabel lblCryptText;
JTextArea encryptedText;
JToggleButton tglbtnNewToggleButton;
JToggleButton tglbtnNewToggleButton_1;
```

Then I have **run()** method which provides the messaging. My question is when I use main method like below so that I run the **run() method** in my connect button when the frame opens(initally it asks username) and ı want it to run the method after connect button:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       client = new ChatClient();
       client.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       client.frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

tglbtnConnect = new JToggleButton("Connect");
            tglbtnConnect.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

```
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                try {
                    client.run();
                    connectInfo.setText("Connected");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        tglbtnConnect.setBounds(12, 36, 106, 25);
```

The problem is when I click on connect, It asks the username then it leaves the gui so that ı can not use any component. Any help or hint is appreciated. You can find my whole class below: https://pastebin.com/N7Ncz7yk

You can find my run method below:

```
private void run() throws Exception {

        // Make connection and initialize streams
        String serverAddress = "localhost";
        Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddress, 9001);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            socket.getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

        // Process all messages from server, according to the protocol.
        while (true) {
            String line = in.readLine();
            if (line.startsWith("SUBMITNAME")) {
                out.println(getName());
            } else if (line.startsWith("NAMEACCEPTED")) {
                userText.setEditable(true);
            } else if (line.startsWith("MESSAGE")) {
                int idx = line.lastIndexOf(">");
                String mssg = line.substring(idx + 1);
                if(rdbtnAes.isSelected() && rdbtnCbs.isSelected()){
                     String key="MZygpewJsCpRrfOr";
                    byte[] encryptionKey = "MZygpewJsCpRrfOr".getBytes();
                    //byte[] plainText = input.getBytes();
                    AES advancedEncryptionStandard = new AES(encryptionKey);
                    byte[] cipherText = advancedEncryptionStandard.encrypt(mssg,key,0);
                    String decryptedCipherText = advancedEncryptionStandard.decrypt(cipherText,key,0);
                    String encrytepdText=new String(cipherText);

                    // APPEND MESSAGE
                     DisplayMessage.append(encrytepdText + "\n" + line.substring(8,idx + 1) + decryptedCipherText + "\n");

                }
                else if(rdbtnAes.isSelected() && rdbtnOfb.isSelected()){
                    String key="MZygpewJsCpRrfOr";
                    byte[] encryptionKey = "MZygpewJsCpRrfOr".getBytes();
                    //byte[] plainText = input.getBytes();
                    AES advancedEncryptionStandard = new AES(encryptionKey);
                    byte[] cipherText = advancedEncryptionStandard.encrypt(mssg,key,1);
                    String decryptedCipherText = advancedEncryptionStandard.decrypt(cipherText,key,1);
                    String encrytepdText=new String(cipherText);

                    // APPEND MESSAGE
                     DisplayMessage.append(encrytepdText + "\n" + line.substring(8,idx + 1) + decryptedCipherText + "\n");

                }
                else if(rdbtnDes.isSelected()&& rdbtnCbs.isSelected()){
                    DES desEncryption=new DES(mssg,0);
                     DisplayMessage.append(desEncryption.encryptedData + "\n" + line.substring(8,idx + 1) + desEncryption.decryptedMessage + "\n");
                }
                else if(rdbtnDes.isSelected() && rdbtnOfb.isSelected()){
                    DES desEncryption=new DES(mssg,1);
                    DisplayMessage.append(desEncryption.encryptedData + "\n" + line.substring(8,idx + 1) + desEncryption.decryptedMessage + "\n");
                }


            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I can not see the pastebin code. Are you closing the ChatClient.frame so that the program would exit (see option EXIT_ON_CLOSE)?

Comment: Please post an MVP. There are hundred of lines to read which is hard to understand.

Comment: @michaek it is visible. Yes like exit on close it is default. Is it related with that?

Comment: Besides a recommendation: use static with care. Read something about MVC (Model View Controller) and separation of concerns and try to change the code. The way it is written one class does all. Furthermore `client.frame` is most likely a finding because frame should not be accessed at this level.

Comment: What does it mean "it leaves the gui" ...?

Comment: If you mean the UI is not responding it looks you are caught in an endless loop. If you need to stay repsonsive you need another `Thread` to listen to the server and update the components from that thread. `while (true)`

Comment: @michaek first of all thanks for your attention, Most of the code is gui components. The problem comes from **run() **method and the use of **frame** I guess. how can ı make the frame accessable so that it does not leave the GUI, I mean my client is static and when I run the method on main it works. when ı carry it on connect button it leaves the gui, how can ı change it?

Comment: like the frame is visible but the components can not be used.

Comment: As it stands the problem can't be understood. Please edit your question: post the code of the run method to show the root of the problem.

Comment: I edited the run() method

Comment: I posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your `client.run()` method you create an infinity loop by writing `while (true)` without `break` or `return`. Because this method is called from the UI Thread from an `ActionListener` your UI is stuck/not responding "not usable".

Solution: Create a new `Thread` which runs the server listening code and update the UI from this thread. Connect should only start that thread with `thread.start()` and then return.